# Web api c# - Obter a rota corrente no controler

Tags: c#, api, aplicação-web

Como obtenho a rota corrente de um endpoint na controler?

Answer (score 1):

O objeto `Request` tem essa informação:

`var route = Request.Path.Value;`

Lembrando que é o caminho relativo, sem o protocolo ( `http`, etc)

Comment: No meu projeto da que o HttpRequestMessage não tem o Path....Saberia o que é?

Comment: quer dizer que não tem o objeto `Path`?

Comment: Eu estava com projeto Web Api clássica (net framework) aí para conseguir a URL usasse Request.RequestUri.AbsolutePath, no net Core é como você disse. O que me ajudou pois precisava fazer isto não dois